# TableView Not Updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have  parse the data from `API` response to `UITableView`.But here i get the response in viewDidAppear method,then after completed response i want update the data to TableView but its not updated.I'm following this methods

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

                [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        // Response here ..Service call  //
                NSLog(@"viewDidAppear running");
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];
    }
```

and also i tried to `[self.tableView reloadData]` but `TableView` not Updated ,can you please suggest me how can i overcome this.Thank you.

Comment: can you show the API Response method

Comment: I guess the *Service call* is asynchronous. And use `dispatch_async` on the main queue rather  than `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Comment: If your service is async you should call reloadData inside the response block when the response data is available, to give you better support provide the request/response mechanism

Comment: its like JSON response @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: its ok can show that code

Comment: the call to reloadData must happen after the download call/service call is finished. You must place that line of code in the completion block of your service call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot call `UITableView#reloadData` from a background thread. So you actually need to schedule just that one on the main thread: call the following methods after webservice call when you get the response after that add this

```
if (yourArray.count>0)
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
}
```

**No need of this**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

                [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        // Response here ..Service call  //
                NSLog(@"viewDidAppear running");
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];
    }
```

Comment: They both run on main thread, the only differences is dispatch_Async runs immediatley, but the performSelectorOnMainthread deals with common run loop modes. I doubt that the issue should be calling the reload data before getting the response from server. THe dispatch_async call you suggested should be in the server call completion block.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri - may be you are right, if questioner shows some code we can easily identify

Comment: Thank it's Working Fine @Karthik

Comment: @G.P.Reddy - is there any issues bro